# How to open activity using alarm manager even when the app is killed?

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager

I'm having a requirement where i need to open an activity at specific time and perform specific task even when the app is killed. That is even when the app is removed from multi-task window pane.

As of now i'm using the alarm manager to achieve this task as shown below.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyScheduledReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
           0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager
          = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
long interval = 60 * 1000; //
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
finish();
```

The onReceive method is as below:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, MyScheduledActivity.class);
 scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);

}
```

The problem is, it opens up the activity when the app is in background. Not when in closed or not in the back stack(mutli-task pane).

Please lighten me up. I'm struggling.

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exercise.AndroidScheduledActivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:name=".AndroidScheduledActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name=".MyScheduledActivity" />
      <receiver android:process=":remote"
                android:name="MyScheduledReceiver" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you please post your manifest file and log

Comment: @Jois, i have added the manifest file.

Comment: when do you exactly want to trigger the broadcastReciever afte rthe app is closed??

Comment: broadcastReceiver will trigger as per the timings. Say for example every hour or soo. During this time, if the app is closed, i need to open the activity and perform usual task

Comment: change getBaseContext to getApplicationContext() in myIntent constructor

Answer (score 1):

start a service and your alarm code in that.Once the alarm is done start your application through notification or as per your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Service, Open your activity through service. [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: .Can we make use of alarm manager along with the services to set the time. I need to start the activity or perform some task during particular time.

Comment: Yes you can do that.